# SQL row_number() - how to ignore nulls?

Tags: sql, null, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, row-number

I need to add counters to users activity, using this query:

```
select PERSON_ID, TIMESTAMP, 
  row_number() over (partition by  PERSON_ID order by  TIMESTAMP asc) as PERSON_COUNTER
from table1;
```

This works well, but it counts also the case where PERSON_ID is null and assigns counters as if null was a name of a user. What I want is the counter to be null in these cases - any ideas?

Comment: @Reporter, doesn't it feel like such an unnecessary nitpick for a pretty basic question?

Comment: @Paul SQL has a widly range of use. And lots of members at stackoverflow has tagged SQL in tag list. So for first filtering it would save time if you can filter on your own startpage. And as you can see this question is  not a question for speciallist sqlserver oracle etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use a query like below

```
select 
PERSON_ID, TIMESTAMP, CASE WHEN PERSON_ID IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE PERSON_COUNTER END AS PERSON_COUNTER
from
(
select PERSON_ID, TIMESTAMP, 
  row_number() over (partition by  PERSON_ID order by  TIMESTAMP asc) as PERSON_COUNTER
from table1
) t;
```

Comment: @Stefanov.sm done

Answer (score 5):

It will be more elegant and without subqueries:

```
select PERSON_ID, TIMESTAMP, 
  iff(PERSON_ID is null, null, row_number() over (partition by  PERSON_ID order by  TIMESTAMP asc)) as PERSON_COUNTER
from table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to filter Nulls

```
      select PERSON_ID, TIMESTAMP, 
     row_number() over (partition by  PERSON_ID order by  
     TIMESTAMP asc) as PERSON_COUNTER
     from table1 where PERSON_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: what about "the counter to be null in these case"?

Comment: Why would anyone want Nulls entries with different timestamps assigned row numbers pretty much utter nonsense. Yes, you could represent null values through a union n show for your assumed concerns n also read the tagline of the Ops query it says " how to ignore nulls"

Comment: Well, that's what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the counter keeps counting, but you don't really care about the values for rows where `PERSON_ID` is null. So just discard them

```
select PERSON_ID, 
       CASE PERSON_ID
         WHEN NULL THEN NULL
         ELSE PERSON_COUNTER
       END as PERSON_COUNTER
FROM (
  select PERSON_ID, TIMESTAMP, 
    row_number() over (partition by  PERSON_ID order by  TIMESTAMP asc) as PERSON_COUNTER
  from table1) T;
```

Or even add a `WHERE` clause on the same level to get rid of the rows if you don't care about them at all

Comment: @DhruvJoshi got here slightly faster though =)

Comment: But (on many DBMS) both of them do not work w/o an alias of the derived table ...

Comment: Fair point. Edited that in